# Plugin for displaying faded background image on NetBeans code editor

Tags: ide, netbeans

I am looking for a plugin to show background images on my NetBeans 8.0. Visual Studio has some cool extension according to **[this article](http://mobilebits.de/Blog/post/2009/06/02/Most-distracting-addin-ever-for-Visual-Studio-Changing-background-images.aspx)**, I wonder if NetBeans has anything equivalent of this. Do you know any?

[edit] To make a bit clearer what I'm after;

- What is must: I should be able to put a background image on my NetBeans code editor pane.
- What would be nice: nothing. It's just one thing: putting a background image of my choice on the code editor on NetBeans.
- Can you show us an example of what you're looking for: please refer to the "this article" link. There is an article behind the link that describes how what I want to do with NetBeans can be done with Visual Studio.

[/edit]

*Actually, I wasn't quite sure if I should ask this on SuperUser or here on Software Recommendations... But there, I've asked it. :)*

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please understand that most of us won't follow up to "this article" to guess your exact requirements :) Please take a look at [this article](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and see if you can [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer. Especially list your requirements as close as possible: what are "musts", what are "nice-to-haves", and are there some possible "no-gos"? This will significantly improve your chances of good answers. Thanks!